# Create custom field type with dynamic data

Tags: plugin-development

I would like to create a custom dropdown field with dynamic data

Ideally I would get data from one of my services, and then inject it dynamically in the HTML select field

I read the plugin documentation on custom field types, but couldn't find anything about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at the [LJ Dynamic Fields plugin](https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-dynamicfields), it sounds like everything you’re after is already doable with this plugin and if not, you can study the code or build upon it.